# How to use fuzzy process.extract on dictionaries which having values has list of values

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-search

Thanks All

If I Want to fuzzy match a string with dictionary where values are in the form of list of values. how can I match each string inside that list and can have output as in dictionary format.

For example:

```
    st = "HTML"
    skills = {
      basic: ["HTML","CSS","JS"],
      framework: ["Angular", "React"]
    }
    for i in st:
        i = floatRemover(i)
        matchString = process.extract(i, skills)
        print(matchString)
```

Here out put is coming like this

```
[(['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'], 100, 'basic')]
```

but my desired output something like this

```
[([('HTML', 100), ('CSS', 30), ('JavaScript', 30)], 'basic')
```

*here matching score is just imaginary.

Is it possible?

and can we set some score like 80 and get data in the form of dictionary which contain key and value which is list which contain only matched strings with match score more than 80

like  this

```
{
   'basic': ['HTML']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over all items in the dictionary `skills` and perform fuzzy match between `st` and the values of keys in the dictionary. Then, store that in a new list `result`.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

st = "HTML"
skills = {
  "basic": ["HTML","CSS","JS"],
  "framework": ["Angular", "React"]
}

for k,v in skills.items():
    if st in skills[k]:
        result = [process.extract(st, skills[k]), k]  
        
print(result)
```

Output:

`[[('HTML', 100), ('CSS', 0), ('JS', 0)], 'basic']`

If you want to create a dictionary with item with highest ratio:

```
d = dict.fromkeys([result[1]], [i[0] for i in result[0] if i[1] == max([i[1] for i in result[0]])])
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'basic': ['HTML']}
```

Alternative solution with list comprehensions:

```
result = [[process.extract(st, skills[k]), k] for k in skills.keys() if st in skills[k]]  
        
print(result[0])
```

Output:

```
[[('HTML', 100), ('CSS', 0), ('JS', 0)], 'basic']
```

Comment: thank you amanb for your answer. I am looking for more of without using loops. Does fuzzywuzzy giving anything which will do automatically?

Comment: `process.extract` gives automatically..but we are using loop because you have string matching lists inside the `skills` dictionary.

Comment: If you had a flat dictionary instead, we wouldn't need a for loop. I have also provided alternative solution with list comprehensions @RamuSompalli

Comment: @RamuSompalli, glad I could help. If this answer solved your problem, you may accept it as answer.